# Understanding PHP event dispatching systems

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-events

I've never done anything event-driven in PHP, only Node.js, so I'm trying to understand how event dispatching systems work in PHP (such as [Laravel events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events), [CakePHP events](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html) and [Symfony event dispatcher](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)).

This example is in the Laravel docs:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\OrderShipped' => [
        'App\Listeners\SendShipmentNotification',
    ],
];
```

Since the lifetime of a PHP script running on Apache is basically the lifetime of the request, does this mean all the event listeners are instantiated with each request?

So if I have 120 listeners in my application (i.e. listed in this `$listen` property), are all 120 of them going to be instantiated every time a page is visited? Or do the listener objects only get instantiated when the appropriate events are dispatched?

It seems quite inefficient for the listeners to be instantiated with each request when in the entire duration of the request there might not even be a single event fired.

Is this something that I should even be concerned about?

Comment: The overhead for an individual event is quite low, when an event is fired it'll look for the appropriate listeners and then instantiate them.

Comment: 120 event listeners seems a bit high outside of an enterprise-grade CRM or ERP or whatnot, but I would think the dispatcher itself is controlling the instantiation of the listener handler based on the event key. So really it's an array that holds your associations, with the second-level associations being instantiated (by the dispatcher) when the first-level condition is met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How an Event Listener system works.

In simplest terms it's just an array of text objects.

So in symfony you might do something like this

```
$eventManager->dispatch('my_cool_event_name', $eventPayload);
```

This will then look for anything that is listening for the event `my_cool_event_name` by just doing an array look up

```
$events = [
    'my_cool_event_name' => [
        'events\notifyController::email',
        'events\notifyController::text',
        'events\notifyController::tweet',
    ],
    'another_event' => [

    ]
];
```

So from the array example above it found 3 events listening on `my_cool_event_name`, it'll then instansiate `events\notifyController` and run the methods passing through the `$eventPayload` to each event.

If you never dispatched `my_cool_event_name` during execution then nothing gets instansiated